# what mic are they using in this trailer/preview

Tags: production

http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/20wfrt/www.newsday.com/entertainment/movies/behind-the-scenes-on-jack-the-giant-slayer-1.4792722/

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to see in the clip but my guess would be the Schoeps cmc6-mk41 - http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/377424-REG/Schoeps_CMC641_SET_Colette_Series_Microphone_Set.html